# Como puedo asociar los datos de un array a un evento .data() en jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, mvc

Estoy intentando realizar la captura de datos de una tabla en html pero no he podido almacenarlos con la funcion ".data()" de jquery para todo esto despues mandarlos en al backend. les dejo mi codigo

```
 $("#grabar").click(function () {
    var contenido = [];
    $("#tabla-detalle tr").each(function (index, item) {
        let cos ={};
        let tds = $(this).find("td")
        cos.plu = tds.filter(":eq(0)").text();
        cos.cantidad = parseInt(tds.filter(":eq(2)").text());
        contenido.push($(cos).data());
    });
    console.log(contenido);
});
```

no se si este este bien y este es el evento de la tabla para poder agregar los datos:}

```
 if ($("plu").val() === "") {
        Swal.fire("Error", "Debe ingresar un plu").then(function () { $("#plu").focus(); });
    } else if ($("#cantidad").val() === "") {
        Swal.fire("Error", "Debe ingresar la cantidad").then(function () { $("#cantidad").focus(); });
    }
    let plu = $("#plu").val();
    let descripcion = $("#descripcion").val();
    let neto = $("#neto").val();
    let cantidad = $("#cantidad").val();
    let total = $("#total").val();
    let i = 1;
    i++;
    let fila = '<tr id="row' + i + '"><td>' + plu + '</td><td>' + descripcion + '</td><td>' + (neto) + '</td><td>' + (cantidad) + '</td><td>' + (total) + '</td> <td class="text-center eliminar" name="eliminar" id="' + i + '"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></td></td></tr>'; //esto seria lo que contendria la fila
    $('#tabla-detalle').append(fila);
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no directamente haces `contenido.push(cos);`? No le encuentro sentido a lo que intentas hacer actualmente. ¿Sabes para que se usa [`$(selector).data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)?

Comment: Según lo que leí en la documentación puedo agregarle un valor al objeto data sin embargo no logro pasar el valor del árray a aquel valor

Comment: Sirve para agregar/obtener [`data-attribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) a objetos del DOM. No lo estas usando ni de la forma que se debe, ni para lo que lo que supone de que deberias usarlo. Es más el problema que tenes se debe principalmente por eso.